# How to do integration test with flutter driver on autocomplete textfield in flutter

Tags: flutter, integration-testing, bdd, autocompletetextview, flutterdriver

How to do integration test with flutter driver on AutoTextCompleteFiled with GlobalKey value. How we can identify the  AutoTextCompleteFiled widget with the Global key and how we can enter text in this widget with flutter driver automation in BDD?

Answer (score 1):

*Here's how you can do it I have given example of flutter_typeahead which is also used for autocomplete*
This is the test case

```
group('App', () {
final saveButton = find.byValueKey('save_button');
final cityField = find.byValueKey('city_field');
final city = 'Mumbai';

FlutterDriver driver;

// Connect to the Flutter driver before running any tests.
setUpAll(() async {
  driver = await FlutterDriver.connect();
});

// Close the connection to the driver after the tests have completed.
tearDownAll(() async {
  driver.close();
});

test('test cities field', () async {
  //for tapping city autocomplete field
  await driver.tap(cityField);
  //for entering city
  await driver.enterText(city);
  //for selecting suggestion or find.text(city) to search by text
  await driver.tap(find.byValueKey(city));
  //for tapping save button
  await driver.tap(saveButton);
});
});
```

This is the autocomplete field 
**Main things to note here is that you need to use key in each item builder widget that will be used later to tap that widget** 
**You can also use find.text(city) for searching by text instead of key**
city name used for testing must be present in the cities list used

```
Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('What is your favorite city?'),
        TypeAheadFormField(
          key: Key('city_field'),
          textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
              controller: this._typeAheadController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'City')),
          suggestionsCallback: (pattern) {
            return getSuggestions(pattern, citiesList);
          },
          itemBuilder: (context, suggestion) {
            return ListTile(
              key: Key(suggestion),
              title: Text(suggestion),
            );
          },
          transitionBuilder: (context, suggestionsBox, controller) {
            return suggestionsBox;
          },
          onSuggestionSelected: (suggestion) {
            this._typeAheadController.text = suggestion;
          },
          validator: (value) {
            if (value.isEmpty) {
              return 'Please select a city';
            }
            return null;
          },
          onSaved: (value) => this._selectedCity = value,
        ),
        TextButton(
          key: Key('save_button'),
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text('Save'),
        ),
      ],
    )
```

Cities List

```
List<String> citiesList = [
'Mumbai',
'Pune',
'Delhi',
'Surat',
'Jaipur',
'Chennai',
'Kolkata',
'Bangalore'
];
```